# Adding space to a text box c#

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a lot of text in a text box (im trying to solve an encryption for homework) but i have laid it out in a fashion thats pretty unclear! What is the easiest way to insert four spaces before and after every | character?

Thank you.

Comment: do u want to include spaces in textbox with text ???

Comment: What he's tried doesn't matter. Obviously what he's tried hasn't worked... or he hasn't tried anything at all. Either way he asked a question. If you can't provide an answer you might consider just ignoring the question next time instead of posting useless comments like this.

Comment: Post some code at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this but the simplest is probably `string.replace("|", "    |    ");`

Comment: Where are those four spaces? Stackoverflow probably ate two of them.

Answer (score 1):

`txtMyText.Text = txtMyText.Text.Replace("|", "    |    ");`

This might work?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to do a `Replace` on the string:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Replace("|", "    |    ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution but I think that its one you will be able to understand.

```
private string GetPaddedString(string str)
{
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char character in str)
    {
        sb.Append("    ");
        sb.Append(character);
        sb.Append("    ");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You just need to pass in the value of the textbox and set what it returns as the text.